# How to Identify the Data Type of Generic Class/Method

Tags: c#, string, generics, types, integer

Here is my code, Which I tried to identify the Generic method data type.

1. First If condition is used to identify the primitive data type.
2. Second If condition is used for T is generic type or class.

   ```
   public T ToObject<T>()
        {
            //T is : int,int?,string,float,decimal 
            if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            {
                //TO DO : Return Value Type
            }    
            //T is Generic List<User> 
            if (typeof(T).IsGenericType)
            {
                //TO DO : Return List of Object
            }
            else
            {
                //T is User 
                //TO DO : Return Object
            }                
            return default(T);
        }
   ```

Comment: What you mean by "fail"? We need more details.

Comment: The purpose of generic code is to be *generic*. If you're inspecting types and branching to type-specific code, you may as well not be using generics at all. As it is, I feel the question is too vague to see what you're *actually trying to achieve here*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Written various times code like the one he wrote. You can't overload simply on restrictions of generics, and there aren't all the restrictions I'd like to use.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand the purpose of this method, what exactly would you do in those branches?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I have DataTable and Based on Type i want to return value, e,g : 
1. If Type Is int,string,decimal,etc Then take value from Table.row[0][0],
2. If Type is class object then get value from first row, 
3. If Type is List then Return List

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Read my above comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` is not a value type, so your first condition breaks straight away.

Its really unclear what you are asking and this seems strange to say the least. However, in your first example `IsValueType` just wont work, what about structs?how are you going to differentiate? You can use the property `IsPrimitive`, but be careful because there are some types that we can think that are primitives, but they aren´t, for example `Decimal`, `String`, `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, and so many more.

```
if (t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(Decimal) || t == typeof(String) || ... )
{
    // Is Primitive, or Decimal, or String
}
```

Yet still, this code wont work for nullable types, they wont be flagged as primitive.

I really think you need to reconsider your design, you are going to have to make so many exceptions and it will break all over the place.

Is generics really what you want here?

FWIW, i think you have a design or architectural problem somewhere else that leads you to need to use a generic method like this, or you have unrealistic expectations about what types are and can be categorised as.

However, if you really have your heart set on this,  you could tentatively use something like the following for "primitive like" types

**Updated** thanks to xanatos sugestions

```
private static readonly Type[] _types = {
      typeof(string),
      typeof(decimal),
      typeof(DateTime),
      typeof(DateTimeOffset),
      typeof(TimeSpan),
      typeof(Guid)
   };

public static bool IsSimpleType(Type type)
{
   Type baseType;
   return type.IsPrimitive || 
          type.IsEnum || 
          _types.Contains(type) || 
          ((baseType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)) != null && 
           IsSimpleType(baseType));
}
```

**Disclaimer**, I take no responsibility for the people you maim and injure with this code

Comment: Why `Convert.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.Object `? `type != typeof(object)`

Comment: @xanatos Yes indeed good point, I'll chuck in some tests and update the code when I get home

Comment: You are even missing the code to detect enums... `Enum` is a base type that isn't really used directly.

Comment: and `Convert.GetTypeCode(type) != TypeCode.Object` will return `true` for anything that isn't `object`... I don't think it is what he wants...

Comment: I suggest to remove `typeof(Enum)` and  then: `Type baseType; return type.IsPrimitive || type.IsEnum || _types.Contains(type) || ((baseType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)) != null && IsSimpleType(baseType));`

Comment: @xanatos thanks for your input, yeah it seemingly can be simplified a lot and be more intuitive

Comment: @xanatos Thanks.

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks it's work form me.
 can you update answer as per "xanatos " suggestions

Comment: @NileshVishwakarma done

Answer (score -2):

```
Type typeValue = typeof(T);
```

you could refer to [typeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof) for more detail